# Anchor links cause element height increase in Safari (iphone)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I encountered a weird bug in Safari (iPhone5) that haven't been able to repeat in any other browser (or even Safari emulators, like Chrome Dev Tools, which makes this hard to debug).

I have one-pager (made with Twittter Bootstrap), with four anchor links. My html structure is like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/#element1">Element1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#element2">Element2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#element3">Element3</a></li>       
    <li><a href="/#element4">Element4</a></li>      
  </ul>
</div>
...
<div class="container">
<div class="row" id="element1">
...
</div>
<div class="row" id="element2">
...
</div>
<div class="row" id="element3">
...
</div>
<div class="row" id="element4">
...
</div>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
 .container
{
    width:100%;
}

.row
{
    min-height:100vh;
    padding-top:0px;
}
```

Now, when I go to my page with Safari, scrolling and links work fine at first. But then, when i navigate to one of the anchor links and **then** scroll, all the "row" elements seem to have increased in height - I have to scroll and scroll to get to next / previous element.

Any ideas what might be causing this? The problem doesn't seem to occur in any other mobile browser (tested mobile Chrome and Android Browser).

Comment: And CSS applied to 'element1' , 'element2' etc?

Comment: The code as given works fine on a 6s and 4s. Are you just testing these on the simulator? If so, I think it's misleading you.

Comment: It works fine on Chrome's iPhone simulator and some other simulators I've tested. The bug only occurs when testing on actual iPhone.

Comment: Jay: There's no css applied to id's except different background-colors currently, they inherit other attributes from .row